# Unable to post variables with jquery post

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

I am trying to pass variables from a modal form to another page. I declare the variables from the form with the id tags in each selection.

Page reloads to test.php, however no variable can be echoed.

javascript

```
var id = $( "#id" ),
name = $( "#name" )

$.post("jqtest/test.php", { device_id: "id", device_name: "name" });
load('jqtest/test.php');
```

test.php

```
echo $_POST['device_name'];
echo $_POST['device_id'];
```

Comment: It is a duplicate because all the other post did was get shot down since i didn't clarify which sections where which....

Comment: @user2338171 It is or it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = $( "#id" ), name = $( "#name" )
/*
if have tag like <input id='id' value='ABC'> and want to get ABC , $( "#id" ).val();

if have tag like <div id='id' >ABC</div> and want to get ABC,$( "#id" ).html();
*/
$.post("jqtest/test.php", { device_id: "id", device_name: "name" });
/*
after get id and name , need
$.post("jqtest/test.php", { device_id: id, device_name: name });
*/

load('jqtest/test.php');
/*
  useless delete this line
  if need callback, ref:
  $.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" })
    .done(function(data) {
    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
    });
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not call load to get the contents of the post!

```
$.post("jqtest/test.php", { device_id: "id", device_name: "name" }, function (data) {
    //handle the response here
    console.log(data);
});
```

Also the use of load like that is wrong, unless you are calling some sort of function.

---

Edit,

Based on your comments, the echo does not work since you are loading a NEW page, you are not dealing with the post code in the Ajax request. If you want to navigate to the page the form submits to, than submit an actual form! You are using Ajax wrong.

Comment: I am using load to simply go to the page or is there a better way of doing that?

Comment: Why would you do to the page and post an Ajax request to it. Makes no sense.

Comment: Either submit a form and let normal html form actions work or learn how Ajax actually works.

Comment: The form is inside a jquery modal that runs through validation checks for the fields. So the real setup is like this...

    if ( bValid ) {
    $.post("jqtest/test.php", { device_id: "id", device_name: "name" 
    };
    //go to test.php

Comment: @user2338171 so the modal has a form and you submit that form to the page you want to go to. You can not magically make an Ajax request and think echoing out will show up on some other request.

Comment: If there is a way to simply pass the variables via post then go to that page and echo them out that is all I'm looking to do. Would submitting the form via jquery post the variables from jscript and follow the action of the form?

Comment: It is called Session variables! But if you are looking to navigate there than do not reinvent forms! Just use a form and post.